# Delete not working for mysql-python connectivity

Tags: python, mysql

I want to delete a record in the table using mysql-python connectivity. Below is the code I tried in python but it is giving error. Same command working fine in mysql alone but not working using python connectivity.

```
def deleterecord():

     conn=py.connect(host='localhost',user='root',passwd='richajain',db='mysql')
     cur=conn.cursor()

     print('\nFor User''s Convenience View Entire Records and Decide Whose Details You Want To Delete')

     displayall()

     sno=int(input('\nEnter The Serial Number Of Medicine Of Which You Want To Delete The Details'))

     cur.execute('delete from Pharmaceuticals where sno= % s',sno)

     conn.commit()
     print('\nYour Record Has Been Deleted ')


     print('\nNow Existing Records Are :')
     displayall()

     cur.close()
     conn.close()
```

The error that is appearing.

```
    For Users Convenience View Entire Records and Decide Whose Details You Want To Delete
    +-----+------------+------------------+------------+------------+-------+------+-------+
    | sno |  medname   |     saltname     |  mfgdate   |  expdate   | price | cost | stock |
    +-----+------------+------------------+------------+------------+-------+------+-------+
    |  1  | Meconeuron | Methylcobalamine | 2019-03-12 | 2021-08-18 |  250  | 275  |   7   |
    |  2  |  Crocine   |   Paracetamol    | 2019-08-11 | 2021-01-15 |  100  | 110  |   9   |
    |  3  |    Ocid    |    Omeprazole    | 2019-04-10 | 2020-07-23 |   50  |  55  |   10  |
    |  4  | citrizine  |  Levo-citrizine  | 2020-01-02 | 2022-06-09 |  120  | 132  |   4   |
    |  5  | Gluconorm  |    Metformine    | 2019-07-08 | 2022-03-29 |  375  | 413  |   10  |
    +-----+------------+------------------+------------+------------+-------+------+-------+

    Enter The Serial Number Of Medicine Of Which You Want To Delete The Details 5

    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\admin\OneDrive\Desktop\medicine details(Anika-12th).py", line 245, in <module>
    deleterecord()      # Function calling to delete the record(s) from the tabl File 
    "C:\Users\admin\OneDrive\Desktop\medicine details(Anika-12th).py", line 131, in deleterecord
    cur.execute('delete from Pharmaceuticals where sno= % s',sno)
    File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-  
    packages\mysql\connector\cursor.py", line 569, in execute
    self._handle_result(self._connection.cmd_query(stmt))
    File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site- 
    packages\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 599, in cmd_query
    result = self._handle_result(self._send_cmd(ServerCmd.QUERY, query))
    File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site- 
    packages\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 487, in _handle_result
    raise errors.get_exception(packet)
    mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
    check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '% s' at line 1
```

Comment: Does it work if there is no space between '%'  and 's'?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `%s`, you can use `?`. This is the most usable way when assigning a variable to an SQL query

```
cur.execute('DELETE FROM Pharmaceuticals WHERE sno=?', (sno,))
```

Comment: @RichaJain Same error ? If yes, maybe try to assign a `string` and not `integer`

Comment: still not working. Apparently same code is working in another system.

Answer (score 0):

I were able to do a delete with success changing you query from:

```
cur.execute('delete from Pharmaceuticals where sno= % s',sno)
```

Change to:

```
cur.execute('delete from Pharmaceuticals where sno={}'.format(sno))
```

Notice that in my example I am using the `format` method from string type. And interpolating the value `sno`.

If you would like to keep with your syntax, you have to remove the `whitespace` between `%` and `s` characters from your query and as a parameter from the `execute` method you have to use a tuple.

```
cur.execute('delete from Pharmaceuticals where sno= %s',(sno,))
```

Here is the link for the documentation with [some examples](https://mysqlclient.readthedocs.io/user_guide.html#some-examples).

Comment: Hey thanks!!   This worked ...                                                                          
cur.execute('delete from Pharmaceuticals where sno= %s',(sno,))